# My program for calculating the final grade doesn't calculate it and I can't tell why

Tags: c++

I've been trying to write a C++ program that calculates your end of year grade (an exercise given by the Google for Education C++ course). The program works, except for the fact that **it doesn't calculate your final grade, instead, it just outputs "0".** I have searched the code and can't seem to find the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int check(int a) {
    if (!(cin >> a)) {
        cout << "Come on, that isn't a score" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

int assignments() {
    int assignment1 = 0;
    int assignment2 = 0;
    int assignment3 = 0;
    int assignment4 = 0;

    cout << "Enter the score for the first assignment. ";
    check(assignment1);
    cout << "Enter the score for the second assignment. ";
    check(assignment2);
    cout << "Enter the score for the third assignment. ";
    check(assignment3);
    cout << "Enter the score for the fourth assignment. ";
    check(assignment4);
    return ((assignment1 + assignment2 + assignment3 + assignment4) / 4 * 0.4);

}

int mid() {
    int midterm = 0;
    cout << "Enter the score for the midterm. ";
    check(midterm);
    return (midterm * 0.15);
}

int finalex() {
    int finals = 0;
    cout << "Enter the score for the final. ";
    check(finals);
    return (finals * 0.35);
}

int participation() {
    int parti = 0;
    cout << "Enter the class participation grade. ";
    check(parti);
    return (parti * 0.1);
}

int main() {
    int assign = assignments();
    int midt = mid();
    int fingra = finalex();
    int partigra = participation();
    cout << "The final grade is: " << assign + midt + fingra + partigra << endl;
}
```

(The reason I have a different program for every grade type is because the course states that you should make as many functions as possible)

Comment: change `check(int a)` to `check(int& a)` and it should work.

Comment: You only change the local variable `a` in `check`. Perhaps you meant `check(int *a)`, `cin >> *a` and `check(&assignment1)`

Comment: You seem to expect variables of type `int` to somehow represent fractions of a grade. Do you know what the word "integer" means?

Comment: Make up your mind. Do you want function `check` to return a value or not? And it most certainly cannot change the value of a variable that is passed by value.

Comment: You haven't made as many functions as possible.

Comment: Shameless plug: [Grades Calculator 95](http://grades95.lebeausoftware.org) :)

Answer (score 1):

Either you should pass value to check() as reference or make check to return input value.

Change

```
int check(int a)
```

to

```
int check(int& a)
```

> Second method

Modify check to

```
int check(int a) {
    if (!(cin >> a)) {
        cout << "Come on, that isn't a score" << endl;
        return a;
    }
}
```

And use return value to assign input to variables. Like

```
int midterm = 0;
    cout << "Enter the score for the midterm. ";
    midterm=check(midterm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `cin >> a` statements updates value of a local variable which is gone as soon as `check()` returns. You want to update value of variables that are actually used for calculating grades. Just change the function `check()` to pass by reference `check(int &a)` or pass a pointer `check(int *a)`